# Multiply with case when statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the amortization amount by days and I can't bypass the NULL.

This is the excel formula:

```
IFS(AND(R$2>$I3,R$1<$J3),(((R$2-$I3)*$O3)-SUM($P3:Q3)),$J3>Q$2,(($J3-Q$2)*$O3))
```

SQL:

Amortized amount * by days

```
CASE WHEN 'GETDATE()' > b.date_sale and 'GETDATE()' < b.expydate
    THEN 
        SUM(case when a.bucket = 'A' then (a.amount/(datediff(dd,b.date_sale, b.expydate)))
   when (a.amount/datediff(dd,b.date_sale, b.expydate)) = 0 then 0     else 0 end) * datediff(dd,b.date_sale, b.expydate) 
         end as 'Admin Inception'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Show us a complete query. (Simplified, if possible.)

Comment: You need at least get rid of the single quotes around the function call `'GETDATE()'` needs to be `GETDATE()`

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag, since obviously that's what you are running (`getdate()`, for example, is specific to that database)